# Writing an equation as divergence of an expression

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator, divergence-theorem

I have expression
$$
\nabla\cdot \mathbf{J(r)} = 
\psi^\dagger\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{A}\nabla^2\psi)
+\psi^\dagger\nabla^2 (\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla\psi)
+\left(\nabla\cdot\left((\nabla^2\psi^\dagger)\mathbf{A}\right)\right)\psi
+\left(\nabla^2(\mathbf{A}\cdot \nabla\psi^\dagger)\right)\psi
$$
here $\mathbf{A}\equiv\mathbf{A(r)}$ is vector field and $\psi\equiv \psi\mathbf{(r)}$ is a scalar field. I want to find $\mathbf{J(r)}$.

Is there any way to write the right-hand side of the above equation as the divergence of some expression, i.e, $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{F(r)}$?